# Lighttpd: pre-file-upload action possible?

Tags: file, upload, triggers, lighttpd

My scenario is like this: on an embedded device we have a web interface using lighttpd and a cgicc-based application. Uploading a new firmware takes a lot of time, especially the CPU has heavy load (which is the typical case in field operation). For example running with 80% CPU usage from 'top' the upload need 5-10 minutes(!), with services off it takes only 1 minute.

Therefore I must implement something which allows me to deactivate the services before file upload starts. Problem is that my CGI will recognize the file upload operation *after* lighttpd uploaded the whole file into a temporary set of files. My only idea is to implement a second button which allows the human operatior to manually disable the services before starting upload. But this is not really elegant.

In Javascript I could hide the second button and simulate a click using the upload button, maybe (can I catch the click for a file input?). But this sound very dirty, especially we use the *unobstrusive Javascript* pattern.

Is there some other way to initiate some pre-file-upload action? Maybe by a module or an other feature of HTTP or browsers etc I don't know?

PS: we need backward compatibility to IE6, so no HTML5 features can be used. We use XHTML 1.0 strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Modern version of lighttpd have improved lighttpd memory management and slightly reduced lighttpd's memory footprint, so this might no longer be an issue for you.

If it still is, then:

[lighttpd mod_magnet](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModMagnet) can be configured to send a trigger:

https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Lua_Trigger_Functions

However, if you disable services, you should probably only do so for a limited time (e.g. two minutes) before automatically re-enabling the services.

Better, identify the exact bottleneck why running both services and upload is slow.  Is the embedded system running out of memory and swapping?  Is the embedded system running out of CPU?